# Memcache basic use in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

So I'm trying to learn how to use memcache. I installed it in my system. I'm running it. I installed the dalli gem.

All that seems to be just fine.

Lets say I'd like to cache my users table.

I put this in my User.rb file:

```
  def self.all_cached
    Rails.cache.fetch('User.all') { all }
  end
```

Then in my controller file, I used to have:

```
@users = User.where(:group_id => current_user.group_id)
```

So now I'd like to have something like:

```
@users = User.all_cached.where(:group_id => current_user.group_id)
```

I'm getting a no method error for where... Any ideas for how I should accomplish this?

Comment: Which method isn't being found? The `all_cached` method or is it actually the `where` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment there, I take it you are getting an error like:

```
undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x00000004d92520>
```

That's because `where` works on a model, but when you do `User.all`, it returns basically an array, and there is no `where` method defined for an array.

You may want to use the `find_all` method for enumerables (and arrays) instead (as seen here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001484), or even try a different approach all together. That's your choice.

Here is the example they give to give you an idea off the bat of how it would work:

```
(1..10).find_all {|i|  i % 3 == 0 }   #=> [3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: Ahh I see. My real question is how people use Memcache in rails for something like this? I find it hard to believe if someone is caching a table, there isn't some easier way of getting to that data?

Comment: however, using your advice, this did seem to work:     @users = all_cached.find_all {|i|  i.group_id == current_user.group_id }

Comment: I've never used it to cache an entire table like that, so I'm not sure how others would recommend using it. Rails will already utilize a level of caching though, so you could conceivably make memcached entries for different types of user retrievals: like "all_users", "users_filtered_on_x", etc. And each time they're first run you shouldn't see too hard a hit.